# Ошибка во время загрузки файла с использованием WinInet

Tags: windows, winapi, pascal, wininet

Здравствуйте. Загружаю файл при помощи WinInet. Ошибка возникает в процессе загрузки данных в момент "падения" сервера. Функция InternetReadFile возвращает True и NumberOfBytesRead = 0, что означает окончание загрузки файла. Но должна быть ошибка, т.к. соединение было разорвано и тем более файл не загрузился до конца. GetLastError возвращает 0.

Я что-то не так делаю? Как выловить эту ошибку?

Участок проблемного кода:

```
  ReadResult := InternetReadFile(Request, @Buffer[BytesRead], BytesToRead, NumberOfBytesRead);

  if not ReadResult then
  begin
    ErrorInfo := Inet.SetLastError;
    ExecError(ErrorInfo.ErrorCode, ErrorInfo.ErrorText); // Исключение
  end;

  if NumberOfBytesRead = 0 then
  begin
    ErrorCode := GetLastError;
    FDownloadDone := True;
    Break;
  end;
```

Comment: Метка C была очень даже в тему, т.к. у меня вопрос не по коду программы а по логике работы WinInet. А на языке C куда больше примеров работы с WinInet чем на приведенном выше языке.

Comment: InternetQueryDataAvailable перед InternetReadFile попробуйте. И сравнивайте потом сколько сообщено и сколько реально прочитано.

Comment: Поищите примеры на гитхабе https://github.com/search?l=pascal&q=InternetReadFile&ref=opensearch&type=Code

Comment: InternetQueryDataAvailable Возвращает также true и 0

Comment: Единственное разумное решение которое я нашел, проверять вручную загрузился ли файл до конца.
Но это не дело, что ошибка не возвращается. А точнее возвращается не всегда. 
PS BytesToRead никогда не равен 0